# PHP.Фреймворк laravel. Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'author_id'

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin, phpstorm

Ребята!! Пишу дипломный проект, проект, как понимаете находится на локальном сервере OpenServer, использует phpmyadmin, в нем возникла ошибка в ходе неверных действий с таблицами в базе данных. Буду очень благодарен за помощь!
Вот ошибки:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'author_id' (SQL: create table `posts` (`post_id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `author_
>   id` bigint unsigned not null, `author_id` bigint unsigned not null, `title` varchar(191) not null, `short_title` varchar(191) not null, `img` varchar(191) null, `descr` text not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updat
>   ed_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')**

Exception trace:

> 1.Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'author_id'")
>   C:\OSPanel\domains\laralove\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement.php:119
>
> 2.PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'author_id'")
>   C:\OSPanel\domains\laralove\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement.php:117

Проблема появилась после команды **php artisan migrate:fresh** - видимо нельзя было её писать в момент того, когда таблицы уже заполнены и проект уже функционирует. После этого из базы данных удалилась одна из таблиц, о которой идет речь в самой верхней цитате.

Если понадобится что либо дополнительно для того чтобы определить в чем дело - скину! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php artisan migrate что вам говорит напишите или что выше описано это и есть ответ на миграцию, и да для более широкого понимания я бы посмотрел сами миграции. Если ушла последняя добавленая таблица можно еще попробовать сочетание php artisan migrate:rollback затем php artisan migrate при условии что в структурах миграций все в порядке должно отработать, это первой командой откатит последнии миграции, затем заного вызвать их останется.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

migrate:fresh подразумевает дроп всех таблиц и заливку всех миграций, попробуйте в ручную удалить все таблицы и проверьте все файлы миграций чтобы не было дублирования создания таблицы posts

Comment: Возможно есть. Тогда пересоздав файлы с миграциями, которые дублируются ошибка должна исчезнуть?

Comment: ошибка возникает в момент накатывания миграций?

Comment: Большое спасибо, разобрался!